# Library Using ThreadLocal Potentially Causing Memory Leaks in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, memory-leaks

I'm using the Box.com Java SDK and the library executes the following ThreadLocal:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> THREAD_LOCAL_DATE_FORMAT =
        new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {
    @Override
    protected DateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    }
};
```

However, I believe it is the cause of my tomcat connection pool issues. Especially since subsequential leaks are reported to be affecting HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor.

> SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.box.sdk.BoxDateFormat$1] (value [com.box.sdk.BoxDateFormat$1@275ab696]) and a value of type [java.text.Simple
>   DateFormat] (value [java.text.SimpleDateFormat@faabb360]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a pro
>   bable memory leak.

Without rewriting large portions of the library, is there a way I handle the situation?

Comment: which version of JDK? I think it's no longer a problem since keys are now weakly referenced.

Comment: Unforunately, I haven't been able to update to Java 8. I'm using Java 7 due the framework restriction.

Answer (score 2):

The message is telling you that Tomcat will replace threads to clear these orphaned `ThreadLocal` values. So, while it's not guaranteed to prevent problems, Tomcat is trying to mitigate the effects of the bug.

In general, this can be a problem because while the weakly-referenced `ThreadLocal` instance is garbage collected, the entry in the thread's map can remain for a while, preventing the value, its class, and its classloader from being garbage collected. However, since the value (`DateFormat`) in this case is from the bootstrap loader, it wouldn't be unloaded anyway and shouldn't be an issue.

To clear these orphans when the application shuts down, you would have to dig into the internals of `Thread` with reflection. Sounds messy!

I would first look for stronger evidence to blame your connection pool problems on this. For example, is there a bug in your connection pool that is exposed by Tomcat's replacement of request threads? Maybe that bug is easier to fix yourself.

Comment: As a point of interest, in my simple benchmark, it looks like constructing the `SimpleDateFormat` in question is faster than actually parsing a date. On my workstation, construction takes about 1.6 ns, while parsing takes 2.2 ns. So, unless your application is *all* about parsing dates, it probably isn't worth caching the parser.

Comment: I've been trying to hunt down the connection pool issue for weeks (maybe even months). I do know that it only began to occur when I updated to hibernate 4.

Comment: @JohnGiotta If you can reliably reproduce the problem, run a test with a version of the Box API that you've patched to remove the `ThreadLocal` altogether, creating a new `SimpleDateFormat` every time `parse()` or `format()` is called. If that fixes things, you have some good evidence to recommend accepting your patch. If not, you'll know you need to keep looking. When you are talking about microseconds, spending 75% longer probably isn't a big deal.

Comment: Sorry, the numbers above are microseconds, not nanoseconds. My workstation is pretty old though, so we are probably talking about differences of less than 1 microsecond per parse.